# Bad: Git Bash on windows 10

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I installed git on my computer with windows 10. Once the installation is complete I create a folder on the desktop, then pressing the right button I click on Git Bash Here and then I write the command git init. The problem is that I don't create any .git folder or anything else can you tell me if it's right so I have if there is any error?

Comment: that directory/folder will be created inside a repo, when you set up one (either when cloning from another repo or when you do `git init .` inside a directory where you will start a git-tracked project).

Comment: @eftshift0 but in fact I did git init but it doesn't create me anything

Comment: You realize that it's a hidden directory, right? What command are you running to check?

Comment: @eftshift0 Ok, that's not how I tried to make a virtual machine that emulated windows 7 and the file was visible. I thought I should see it even now

Comment: but if instead I want to create a file and write to it inside, then when I do git add and after git commit does it modify the file or not?
Because I tried to do this but when I enter the commit I don't see what I wrote in the working area file